# Merging XML file with MySQL table

Tags: mysql, xml, merge

I have XML file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<results>
  <row id="100"><name>name blah</name></row>
  <row id="200"><name>name blah blah</name></row>
  <row id="300"><name>name blah blah blah</name></row>
</results>
```

...and a simple MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE `names` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I would like to merge those two things in a way to update my table with non-existing rows from XML file.

What's the easiest and painless as possible way to accomplish this considering XML file and MySQL table consist of more than 100k rows and I would like to run this update once a week or so...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LOAD XML](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html) statement + its REPLACE clause in MySQL 5.5

Code example -

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'names.xml'
REPLACE
INTO TABLE names
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<row>';
```

Another way - [Data Import tool](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/data-export-import.html) (select XML format and Append/Update mode)

Comment: Interesting and quick solution! Thanks! However, I'm not sure if I will be able to start mysql with --xml option on my server :( Will try other solutions now...

Comment: You shouldn't start mysql with --xml option! LOAD XML is a statement that supported by MySQL 5.5. Just use it. I have done this without any problems.

Comment: Uh... My provider is still on MySQL v5.0 :-/ I doubt that it will be upgraded soon... I will see what is possible, this solution seems like the fastest one... I would like to make that script super-automated and forget about it for the rest of my life lol

Comment: Try out tool, in new version we will support data import + command line.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions but I still think that I will have problems with my ISP's outdated applications... I could test it locally (I suppose that navicat, which I use, could also do same thing) but my idea was to make a php script and run a CRON job on my server once in a while to update my table...

Answer (score 1):

Mysql has some [XML support](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/xml-in-mysql5.1-6.0.html#xml-5.1-importing) as of v5.1. Although the xml format is different it's still a place to start.

To be honest the overhead of iterating through that xml file and doing [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE IT UPATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) or [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html), isn't that huge. It should take less than an hour to parse and update the database.

Comment: Give me the total time when you do, I'm curios to see how far off I was :D

Comment: Ok, sure will! =) I'm also curious about it =)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use load xml statement you can use powershell in order to convert your xml file into a csv.

```
$destTXT = "c:\file.txt"
[xml]$xml = (gc c:\file.xml)
$xml.results.row |
select @{ L = 'ID';     E = { $_.id} },
       @{ L = 'Name';   E = { $_.name } } | export-csv $destTXT -NoTypeInformation
(gc $destTXT) -replace('"','') | Out-File $destTXT -Force
```

Your txt file will become this

```
ID,Name
100,name blah
200,name blah blah
300,name blah blah blah
```

and you will be able to use load data statement.